# Not able to use sort() inside of map function

Tags: javascript, couchdb

The documents in my couchdb look like this:

```
 { 
   docType: "event",
   tags: ["bb","aa","cc"],
   ...
  }
```

I would like my couchdb view function, to emit a sorted array of tags, so I tried:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.docType == 'event') {
        if (doc.tags.length > 0) {
          emit(doc.tags.sort(), doc._id);
        }
     }
  }
```

But this (**.sort()**) is not working as expected: The result shows only documents, where the tags array has only one entity (tags.length = 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by the help of the couchDB Slack channel. sort() wants to change  the positions of the elements in the original array, which is not intended by the view function. You can see exceptions of the javascript engine for each array, to be sorted and which has more than one entries. Need to switch the log level of couchdb to "debug" before.

Using the spread operator to create a new array solved the problem:

```
 emit([...doc.tags].sort(), doc._id);
```